# SSKeychain: Accounts not stored in iCloud?

Tags: ios, macos, icloud, sskeychain

I'm using sskeychain (https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain) to store my accounts and passwords in the IOS keychain. I assume, that if I store an account, it should be available on my other device. But it doesn't appear there.

I read my accounts with this code:

```
NSArray *arr=[SSKeychain accountsForService:@"Login"];
for (NSString *s in arr) {
    NSLog(@"Account: %@",s);
}
```

and get this (only shown one entry, the others are similar):

```
Account: {
acct = "friXXXXXter@XXXX.com";
agrp = "3B4384Z34A.de.gondomir.LocalButler";
cdat = "2014-05-09 22:55:08 +0000";
mdat = "2014-05-09 22:55:08 +0000";
pdmn = ak;
svce = Login;
sync = 0;
tomb = 0;
}
```

But this doesn't appear on the other device. Both devices have IOS 7.1.1.
I store the password with this line:

```
  [SSKeychain setPassword:self.passwortField.text forService:@"Login" account:self.userField.text];
```

I have switched on keychain sharing in Xcode and have a keychain group "de.gondomir.LocalButler" listed there.

Am I missing something? Must the service name something special?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case this is still relevant for you I managed to find the solution. (works for >=iOS7)

Don't use the static methods of SSKeychain to write your credentials. Instead use `SSKeychainQuery` and set the synchronizationMode to `SSKeychainQuerySynchronizationModeYes` like this

```
NSError *error; 
[SSKeychain setAccessibilityType:self.keychainAccessibilityType];
SSKeychainQuery *query = [[SSKeychainQuery alloc] init];
query.service = service;
query.account = account;
query.password = password;
query.synchronizationMode = SSKeychainQuerySynchronizationModeYes;
[query save:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error writing credentials %@", [error description]);
}
```

The static convenience methods on `SSKeychain` use the default synchronization mode `SSKeychainQuerySynchronizationModeAny` causing credentials not to be synchronized with the iCloud keychain.

Additionally, make sure your devices have Keychain via iCloud enabled (Settings>iCloud>Keychain). You might also want to enable `Keychain Sharing` in your targets Capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

After I have a new project I tried the answer of MarkHim, it works.
I used swift now, so here is my working code:

```
    let account = defaults.objectForKey("Sync_toPhoneNumber") as? String
    SSKeychain.setAccessibilityType(kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock)

    var error:NSError?
    let lookupQuery = SSKeychainQuery()
    lookupQuery.synchronizationMode = .Yes
    lookupQuery.service = "DasDing"
    lookupQuery.account = account

    let password = SSKeychain.passwordForService("DasDing", account: account, error: &error)
    if error == nil {
        commandKey = password!
    } else {
        print("Error für \(account): \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        commandKey = ""
    }


    // query all accounts for later use
    let allQuery = SSKeychainQuery()
    allQuery.service = "DasDing"
    do {
        let dict = try allQuery.fetchAll()
        print("Accounts:")
        for acc in dict {
            print(acc["acct"]!)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("keine Accounts")
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

That's for reading, for writing you must delete the account first (if you want to change the password):

```
    let account = defaults.objectForKey("Sync_toPhoneNumber") as? String
    SSKeychain.setAccessibilityType(kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock)

    SSKeychain.deletePasswordForService("DasDing", account: account)

    let newQuery = SSKeychainQuery()
    newQuery.service = "DasDing"
    newQuery.account = account

    newQuery.password = str?.uppercaseString
    newQuery.synchronizationMode = .Yes
    try! newQuery.save()
```