# iCloud Keychain notify on update

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sskeychain

I'm using the new iCloud Keychain feature implemented by SSKeychain. I set `kcQuery.synchronizationMode = SSKeychainQuerySynchronizationMode.Yes` to my passwords

Does iCloud Keychain now work? Will it be synchronized to my other iDevices?

How long does it take before my items will pushed to iCloud?

Is there a method which notifies me if new passwords reached my device?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Would be awesome if you could share it

Comment: nope. I opened an issue at bugreport.apple.com but its still open without any comment :(

Comment: In the meantime I found a solution, that worked for me. See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution and answered in another question. 
[SSKeychain: Accounts not stored in iCloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579343/sskeychain-accounts-not-stored-in-icloud/34785612#34785612) - see at the bottom

> Does iCloud Keychain now work? Will it be synchronized to my other iDevices?

Yes, if `Settings > iCloud > Keychain` is enabled

> How long does it take before my items will pushed to iCloud?

Seems like instantly.

> Is there a method which notifies me if new passwords reached my device?

No.

---

Don't use the static methods of SSKeychain to write your credentials. Instead use `SSKeychainQuery` and set the synchronizationMode to `SSKeychainQuerySynchronizationModeYes` like this

```
NSError *error; 
[SSKeychain setAccessibilityType:self.keychainAccessibilityType];
SSKeychainQuery *query = [[SSKeychainQuery alloc] init];
query.service = service;
query.account = account;
query.password = password;
query.synchronizationMode = SSKeychainQuerySynchronizationModeYes;
[query save:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error writing credentials %@", [error description]);
}
```

The static convenience methods on `SSKeychain` use the default synchronization mode `SSKeychainQuerySynchronizationModeAny` causing credentials not to be synchronized with the iCloud keychain.

Additionally, make sure your devices have Keychain via iCloud enabled (Settings>iCloud>Keychain). You might also want to enable `Keychain Sharing` in your targets Capabilities.

Comment: did this help you @flashspys?